# How to replay data from two tables with different time column types in DolphinDB?

Tags: time, streaming, dolphindb, nanotime, replay

I want to play back data from two tables. If the time columns of the two tables are of different types, for example, TIME and NANOTIME respectively, does it affect the result?

Any potential pitfalls or best practices I should be aware of? Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can play back data from multiple tables, even if the time column types are different. However, if you expect the data to be replayed in the order of the timestamps, make sure that the precision of the output time column is at least as fine as the highest precision of the time columns being played back. For example, if the columns of TIME and NANOTIME are played back concurrently, the precision of the time field in the output table must be at least NANOTIME, otherwise the results may be out of order.